# case statement is not working properly

Tags: oracle

I have a table `supplier`. I want to concat values of two columns `contact_namber2`,`contact_number3` of table with comma separator and put it in a alias field 'contact'. I have used case statement for null fields.
Such as if `contact_namber2` is null then `contact_number3` will be in alias field.
here is my query:

```
 SELECT supplier_Name,supplier_Address,supplier_reference,contact_Number1,contact_number2, contact_number3,   
  (case 
   when contact_number2 is null then contact_number3 
    when contact_number3 is null then contact_number2 
    when contact_number3 is null and contact_number2 is null then 0
  when contact_number2 is not null and contact_number3 is not null then  CONCAT(CONCAT(contact_number2,','), contact_number3)
   end)
   as contact
FROM SUPPLIER;
```

fourth condition is not working it is showing error.But if I only use 4th condition in the case statement then it works.